# Unable to "go get" module from private github repo on centos 7

Tags: go, github, go-get, private-repository

I am unable to "go get" module from private github repo

I getting following error message

```
go get 
go: github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx-service@v0.0.0-20230419012042-5a43328285a5: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /usr/local/bin/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/e3eb4c4c224c608f41c609b576ad32d5a979877e8a7f951b716f1242957c7ddd: exit status 128:
        remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
        remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
        fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx-service/
```

I tried with the following method. Added the the github credentials in `~/.netrc`:

```
machine github.com 
login <username> 
password <Personal Access Token>`
```

Added the following entries in `~/.gitconfig` file

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Added the environment variable

```bash
export GOPRIVATE=github.com/<username>/*
export GO111MODULE=on
```

Still getting the same Authentication error.

Comment: Try these: 1. rollback the changes to `~/.gitconfig` unless you want to authenticate with ssh keys; 2. rollback the changes to `~/.netrc`; 3. since you accept storing plain password  to file, use `https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store` is more easy. Run `git config --global credential.helper 'store'` to use this helper; 4. run `git clone https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx-service.git` once to make sure your `Personal Access Token` is stored; 5. try `go get` again.

Comment: Thank you @ZekeLu it worked after rolling back the changes to ~/.gitconfig and ~/.netrc

And did following changes


export GOPRIVATE=github.com/<private org>
export GOPROXY=direct

git config --global url."https://<PAT>@github.com/".insteadOf https://github.com/

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! 1. `GOPROXY=direct`, don't do this. It affects all modules. Setting `GOPRIVATE` is enough. 2. `url."https://<PAT>@github.com/".insteadOf github.com`, in my opinion, a git credential helper is better than this.

Answer (score 0):

Github has disabled simple password authentication from command line interfaces since 2021. Take a look at the third line of the first terminal output block you've sent in your question.

You should [create an ssh key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) and add it to your machine's ssh-agent or install the [github-cli](https://cli.github.com/) package and login through it.

Here are instructions to `go get` using SSH:
https://gist.github.com/StevenACoffman/866b06ed943394fbacb60a45db5982f2

Comment: But it supports personal access token which is an alternative to using password. See https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#using-a-personal-access-token-on-the-command-line.